# How do I limit a React input field to a parent min and max props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-props

I am quite new to react here. I am trying to constrain my input to min -10 and max 10 input value. I have it so the input can accept input and I am trying to use hooks useState and useEffect to try to change and set the value in the input. No matter what is in the input when you click off of it it should be constrained to -10 or 10. I know there is onBlur to trigger a function or state for that, but I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appricated.

```
// For reference, this component is rendered
// by its parent like this:
//
// const ParentForm = () => {
//   const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
//   return (
//     <NumberSelector
//       min={-10}
//       max={10}
//       value={value}
//       onChange={setValue}
//       css={{ background: theme.white }}
//     />
//   )
// }

const NumberSelector = ({
  min = -10,
  max = 10,
  value,
  onChange: setValue,
  className,
}) => {
  const [tempValue, tempSetValue] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [tempValue])
  return (
    <div
      css={{
        display: "flex",
        border: `3px solid ${theme.richBlack}`,
        borderRadius: 5,
      }}
      className={className}
    >
      <StepButton
        aria-label="Reduce by one"
        tabIndex="-1"
        onClick={() => {
          setValue((prev) => prev - 1)
        }}
      >
        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <rect x="0" y="6.5" width="16" height="3" fill={theme.richBlack} />
        </svg>
      </StepButton>
      
      <input
        type="text"
        maxLength={Math.max(min.toString().length, max.toString().length + 1)}
        css={inputStyles}
        value={tempValue}
        onChange={(e) => tempSetValue(e.target.value)}
      />

      <StepButton
        aria-label="Increase by one"
        tabIndex="-1"
        onClick={() => {
          setValue((prev) => prev + 1)
        }}
      >
        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <rect x="0" y="6.5" width="16" height="3" fill={theme.richBlack} />
          <rect x="6.5" y="0" width="3" height="16" fill={theme.richBlack} />
        </svg>
      </StepButton>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NumberSelector

NumberSelector.propTypes = {
  min: PropTypes.number,
  max: PropTypes.number,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `NumberSelector` component is completely controlled from the parent, you should not have local state to store the value. The `useEffect` is also unnecessary.

You can then attach an `onBlur` handler to clamp the value.

```
<input
    type="text"
    maxLength={Math.max(min.toString().length, max.toString().length + 1)}
    value={value}
    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    onBlur={e => {
      if (value && !isNaN(value))
        setValue(Math.min(max, Math.max(min, value)));
    }}
/>
```

For the increment and decrement buttons, you need to check that the value will not exceed the valid range after incrementing.

```
<StepButton
    aria-label="Reduce by one"
    tabIndex="-1"
    onClick={() => setValue(Math.max(min, value - 1))}>
// ...
<StepButton
    aria-label="Increase by one"
    tabIndex="-1"
    onClick={() => setValue(Math.min(max, value + 1))}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React.

As I understand you are looking for the numeric value. Then:

```
 <input
    type="number"
    min={min}
    max={max}
    css={inputStyles}
    value={tempValue}
    onChange={(e) => tempSetValue(e.target.value)}
  />
```

For more information [Input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: type needs to remain "text" so no matter what the input is, it will always return a number onBlur or when clicking the step buttons. So if you put in some letters and click away it will default to "1" or if you put letters in and click the step buttons it will start at "1"

Comment: Min and max and everything are already set at const NumberSelector

Answer (score 0):

Usually it isn't recommended to use `useEffect` for any side-modifications.

You can try having some custom handling in the `onChange`

```js
const onTempChange = (e) => {
    // default to 1 if no input is entered
    let tempFloat = parseFloat(e.target.value || '1');
    // default to 1 if input is invalid
    if (isNan(tempFloat) {
        tempFloat = 1;
    } else {
        tempFloat = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, tempFloat));
    }
    // usually you name the setter something like setTempValue
    tempSetValue(tempFloat);
};

return (
    // ...
    <input ... onChange={onTempChange} />
);
```

Obviously there's room for improvement with the code, but that's the gist of one way you can control the input value given to the setter.

If you want this to only happen after the user leaves the input, then you'll just need to listen to another event (onFocusOut iirc?).

Hope this helped.